# Check if letter in the alphabet is a vowel, if so print the vowel, otherwise print the consonant (python)

Tags: python, loops

I'm beginning python and this seems like it should simple but cant crack it.

I have to create a list with the alphabet in it then print whether each item is a vowel or consonant. I could use some help. Right now it just tells me that every letter is a consonant.
Thank you.

```
alphabet =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

for letter in alphabet:
    if letter in alphabet == ['a','e','i','o','u']:
        print (f'{letter} is a vowel')
    else:
        print(f'{letter} is a consonant')
```

Comment: yeah you don't need to do in alphabet == ['a','e','i','o','u'],  just if letter in ['a','e','i','o','u']

Comment: Try using ordinary English words to explain how you want `letter` to relate to the list of vowels. Notice how you *don't* mention the word "alphabet"? Notice how you use the word "in" immediately before describing the list? Notice how you use the word "letter" almost directly before "in"? The Python syntax is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the point of `if letter in alphabet == ['a','e','i','o','u']` is.

Instead, try something like this.

```
alphabet =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

for letter in alphabet:
    if letter in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
        print (f'{letter} is a vowel')
    else:
        print(f'{letter} is a consonant')
```